# callback для console.log?

Tags: node.js

Каким образом можно удостовериться что console.log полностью завершил запись в поток? 
Либо можно использовать какую то другую функцию с аналогичным функционалом?

Comment: console.log - это вообще не запись в поток, оно просто по умолчанию настроено печататься. Возможно, вам нужен process.stdout

Comment: А как убедиться, что  process.stdout.write  
записал полностью, переданную строку?

Comment: @andreymal, в nodejs `console.log` это обертка над `process.stdout`

Comment: @overthesanity [по стандарту](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/) это не обязательно (теоретически это может быть и графическое окно, как в браузерах), а stdout нетрудно заменить на что угодно другое, так что лучше бы на это не полагаться

Comment: @andreymal, стандарт это одно, а вот реализации, понятное дело, везде разные, но если в данном случае речь зашла о ноде, то можете взглянуть на его сурсы и увидите stdout

Comment: @overthesanity я уже заглядывл в сорцы и видел там поле `stream`, в котором вместо stdout может быть что угодно. И да, реализации это одно, а стандарт общий — реализация может быть в будущем изменена, а стандарт вряд ли сильно поменяется, поэтому лучше полагаться на стандарт и не использовать console.log с целью управления stdout'ом